# Convert string of numbers to array of numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app, I have a textfield in which the user enters something like this

```
"1,2,3,4"
```

which gets stored to the database. Now, when I want to use the inner numbers, i have two options:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(',')
```

OR

```
string.scan(/\d+/) do |x|
    a << x
end
```

Both ways i get an array like

```
 ["1","2","3","4"]
```

and then i can use the numbers by calling to_i on each one of them.
Is there a better way of doing this, that converts

```
"1,2,3" to [1,2,3] and not ["1","2","3"]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
str.split(",").map {|i| i.to_i}
```

but the idea is same to you....

Comment: And in 1.8.7p302: `str.split(',').map(&:to_i)`

Comment: I thought &:to_i was kinda frowned upon due to performance issues. No? Good for people to know that it exists though for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
t = "1,2,3,4".split(',').collect{|n| n.to_i}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 1.9.3 you can do the following:

No space after the comma:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(',')  # => ["1","2","3","4"]
```

With the space after the comma:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(', ')  # => ["1,2,3,4"]
```

No space after the comma:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(',').map(&:to_i)  # => [1,2,3,4]
```

With a space after the comma, you are going to get this:

```
"1,2,3,4".split(', ').map(&:to_i)  # => [1]
```

Answer (score -3):

You can do it by following method:-
"1,2,3,4".split(/,/)

This will give you following result:-

["1", "2", "3", "4"]

Thanks....

Comment: Question is how to get `[1,2,3,4]` :p